# ¿Qué es WSGI y cuándo debería usarlo?

Tags: python, web, aplicación-web, gunicorn

Por ejemplo, [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) es un "WSGI HTTP Server". No he encontrado una buena explicación.

¿Alguien me puede explicar WSGI en forma sencilla? y ¿Cuándo debería usarlo?

Comment: lo buscaste en google?

Comment: Sí, pero no pude encontrar una buena explicación en forma sencilla.

Comment: Entonces, aclara que buscaste, que entendiste y que no entendiste, asi sabemos que hay que explicar... porque si pones eso en google, salen montones de explicaciones....

Comment: Por si te interesa te dejo una [guía](https://montesariel.com/es/blog/post-3) sobre como configurar una aplicación Django en Apache usando WSGI

Answer (score 1):

Una explicación simplista y ELI5 es que WSGI es una parte del funcionamiento interno de Python que hace de puente entre un servidor web y una aplicación de python.

Para un usuario normal esta capa del funcionamiento de python sería transparente y es habitual utilizarlo junto con otras librerias que expanden las posibilidades.

Por ejemplo el microframework `FLASK` ya contiene un servidor WSGI compatible, un motor de plantillas `Jinja` y sus propias funciones que facilitan el trabajo de crear una aplicacion web con python.

El uso de `gunicorn` se aconseja porque si bien Flask ya tiene su propio servidor WSGI, éste no es capaz de atender varias peticiones a la vez, tiene un rendimiento inferior y su uso está pensando durante el desarrollo de la aplicación por lo que se utiliza gunicorn JUNTO con Flask para reemplazar el servidor de pruebas para el despliegue y uso normal por los usuarios de tu app.

Es una explicación muy simplista (y en algun punto quizas erronea) pero espero que con esto sepas entender mejor las explicaciones más elaboradas que encuentres en Google